# Query all where list id has user id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get all the properties, in a watchlist(s) where the list has a user id.

The relationship is set up as follows.

Each watchlist is related to a user id. Each Property has a watchlist id.

I need all properties, in all the watchlists belonging to that user.

The watchlist gets the user_id automatically upon creation.

Here are my models

Watchlist

```
public function properties(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\WatchedProperties');
    }

    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

WatchedProperties

```
public function watchlist(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Watchlist');
  }
```

Query
Gets all books in every list disregarding user ids and list ids

```
$Watchlists = WatchedBooks::all();
```

Currently gets all books regardless of userid.

I need all books in all of the user's lists.

A user could have multiple lists
List  A
List  B

So something like
All books from all lists where the list id is related to user id.

This is what the Watchlist DB looks like
[WatchlistDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss1XZ.png)

This is what the WatchedBooks DB looks like
[Books in watchlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYLoY.png)

Comment: if i'm not mistaken watchlist mean the book list you are going to read and WatchedBooks ,mean books you've read in the watchlist right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a beautiful solution for this: you can add a `->hasManyThrough` relation to the user model. You can find more information about this type of relation in [the Laravel documentation about Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

The user model will look like this:

```
class User extends Model {

    [...]

    public function watchedBooks()
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\WatchedBook', 'App\Watchlist');
    }

    [...]

}
```

Then you can get all the `WatchedBooks`, associated with the user, using

```
$user->watchedBooks;
```

or

```
$user->watchedBooks()->yourBuilderQueryHere()->get();
```

Comment: This solution is better than the one I provided, since the relationships are all one-to-many. I'll leave mine as a "working alternative", but this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: So i need the inverse of lists in the user model? I currently only have lists belong to user, not users have many lists

Comment: Yes, you would need to add a hasMany('App\Watchlist')

Comment: I'm confused. Do i not need a query in my controller to pass to my view, and do a for each loop

Comment: No, you won't. If you have the `$user` variable present in your view. You can use the 'magic' property.

Comment: The hasmanythrough is giving errors 'ErrorException thrown with message "include(C:\Users\andre\Dropbox\College\Project\Rentable\vendor\composer/../../app/Watchlist.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: It means that it can't find the class. Do you use the right namespaces? Maybe a spelling error?

Comment: Spelling error. Thats working brillinant thanks. Is it possible to user the $user-watchedProperties to access elements such as title?

Comment: Just another quick question. When I delete the wathclist, the related properties stay there. Can i delete  by the hasthough relationship?

Comment: Yes, you can use `$to_be_deleted_model->yourRelationship()->delete()` to delete all of the related models.

Answer (score 0):

whereHas allows you to query in relationships. More information on this can be found at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
$Watchlists = WatchedBooks::whereHas('watchlist', function($query) use ($user_id){
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
})->get();
```

The script above gets all WatchedBooks that are associated with a Watchlist that is owned by a user ($user_id).

Comment: Where is the value from $user_id coming from. Should it not be auth

Comment: You could set $user_id = Auth::id();. I'm not sure how Laravel would respond with calling "Auth" in a subquery.