# Deleting an item by a hasthrough relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relational-database, eloquent

I was recomended to use a has though relationship to access all of a users books in all their lists. So if a user has 3 lists and 3 books in each. I can accessall 9 books at once.

This works fine thanks to this answer so SO -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386095/9277589

How would I go about deleting the books, when I delete the list. Currently the list deletes, but the books don't.

This is how I access the books in my view. `$user->WatchedBooks`

I have tried this

```
public function destroy($id){

$user = Auth::user();
$Watchlist = Watchlists::where('id', $id)->first();

if($Watchlist->user_id == Auth::id()){
  $Watchlist->delete();
  return redirect('watchlist');
} else {
  return redirect('watchlist');
}

if($user->WatchedBooks == $user){
  return redirect('watchlist');
} else {
  return redirect('watchlist');
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you setup your foreign key with on delete cascade?

Comment: As in the has through relationship. In my user model i have a hasthrough relationship. Use has books through watchedlists. That is access by $user->watchedBooks

Comment: From what I understand you need to be concerned with a hasMany relationship of list->book. With onDelete('cascade') so when you delete the list, the related books delete as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your migration for creating the table

```
     Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books')->onDelete('cascade');
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your foreign key with the `onDelete('cascade)` method in your watchlist migration file:

```
$table->foreign('watched_book_id')->references('id')->on('watched_books')->onDelete('cascade');
```

or you can do this programmatically by using the query builder and the `delete()` method, which will look like this:

```
function yourDeleteMehod() {
    [..]

    $watchlist()->watchedBooks()->delete();
    $watchlist()->delete();

    [..]
}
```

This doesn't require a database change and allows you to have `WatchedBooks` without having a `Watchlist` attached.